# Change object of other class qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt and C++, after click on menu item second window appears, and after click on a button in second menu (slot saveData()), I want to change object (obj_map) of class MainMenu. Is it possible, and how to do it the best way? Because I now cannot modify obj_map, because it is in different class. I tried to do something with pointers, but the result was a segmentation fault.

Main Window:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    map obj_map;

public Q_SLOTS:
    void saveMap();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Other window which appears after click in on menu item in main window.

```
namespace Ui
{
    class PreferencesWindow;
}

class PreferencesWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PreferencesWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
public Q_SLOTS:
    void saveData();
private:
    Ui::PreferencesWindow *uip;
};
```

From here I need to change obj_map

```
void PreferencesWindow::saveData()
{
     // FROM HERE I NEED TO CHANGE obj_map
}
```

Preferences object is created in a slot:

```
void MainWindow::saveMap()
{
    PreferencesWindow *p = new PreferencesWindow();
    p->show();
}
```

Comment: How and where is created `PreferencesWindow` object?

Comment: @jpo38 I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `PreferencesWindow` objects are created by `MainWindow`, the easiest is to have `PreferencesWindow` objects store a pointer to `MainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow;
class PreferencesWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PreferencesWindow(MainWindow *parent = 0);
public Q_SLOTS:
    void saveData();
private:
    Ui::PreferencesWindow *uip;
    MainWindow* m_mainwindow;
};
```

Pass the pointer upon construction:

```
void MainWindow::saveMap()
{
    PreferencesWindow *p = new PreferencesWindow( this );
    p->show();
}
```

Then use it:

```
PreferencesWindow::PreferencesWindow(MainWindow *parent) : 
    QWidget( parent ),
    m_mainwindow( parent )
{

}

void PreferencesWindow::saveData()
{
    // FROM HERE I NEED TO CHANGE obj_map
    m_mainwindow->obj_map.....it's accessible!
}
```

Comment: good idea, but passing this pointer to PreferencesWindow will cause that everything will stay in the same window.

Comment: No, what causes this is calling `QWidget( parent )` in `PreferencesWindow` constructor. If you call `QWidget( NULL )`, they will remain separate.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **signals and slots**: when `saveData()` is called, **emit** a signal, like `emit saveDataClicked()` and catch that signal in the `MainWindow` with a slot called `change_obj_map`. There, you can do your changes.
So, in `MainWindow` you can write:

```
connect (PreferencesWindow, SIGNAL(saveDataClicked()), this, SLOT(change_obj_map());
```

and then in the slot:

```
void change_obj_map()
{
  // Do your changes here
}
```

Another way is having a local `obj_map` in `PreferencesWindow` that is a pointer to the address of `obj_map` in `MainWindow`. So, when you create `PreferencesWindow`, you can just pass the address of `MainWindow`'s `obj_map` to the constructor and assign that address to the local variable `obj_map`.